# Can I create an array variable with Pointers? How?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Now, I have a vector called "list" of 1000 elements of type String. 
This Vector is filled dynamically by a recursive function that discovers files in one directory and load its.

Can I use arrays to keep a list of the elements that takes up only a minimum storage space required? How?

Comment: If you have a static number of elements, yes, you should use array instead of vector.

Comment: @Michael is that what he was asking? And clearly, if there's scanning of a directory involved, it is not static.

Comment: @W.B. yes it is *probably* not static but he also specified that there is 1000 elements.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, what I meant is that I **now** have an array/vector of 1000 elements, what I want to be able to do is to make sure that it fits the content in the best possible way.

I chose 1000 because it was simply the maximum number of songs that came on my pen drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can most definitely create an array of pointers to std::string elements.

These elements will still take up space in memory though so if you goal was to save space you can forget this strategy.

A simple way to save space is to not have your vector start out at size 1000. Vectors only take minimal space and then grow. That is one of their design goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can by doing:

```
std::string * list = new std::string[1000];
```

and then remembering later on to:

```
delete [] list;
```

But if you're going to be doing this dynamically, then a vector would be better.  Why allocate 1000 elements when you might only need 300?  Also not really sure why you want to use a pointer here.

Answer (score 1):

A small memory footprint is possible by storing each string in a Node containing a char[] allocated according to the string length and a pointer to the next Node, i.e., a singly linked list.

That said: why worry about O(1000) strings of moderate length?

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
I don't know "Node" list. The delve it immediately.